# Tabulator ajaxProgressiveLoad scroll keep doing ajax call at background

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I noticed sometimes even if I requested one-page data, but in the background, I see the
ajax calls keep going with increment number of pages.
So like if I requested data for
page=1?pageSize=100 and after completing the call I see another call with
page=2?pageSize=100
page=3?pageSize=100
page=4?pageSize=100
and so on.

```
   I have a function that initializes the tabulator table with a progressive load scroll.
   Every time before initializing the table I destroy the existing tabulator, so that 
   tabulator will not complain about reinitialize issue.
```

Comment: The whole point of progressive loading is to load paginated data silently in the background one page at a time. without seeing how your table is setup it is hard to offer any advice. please post a link to a JSfiddle or codepen that shows your table in operation

Comment: You probably want the ajaxProgressiveLoad option set to 'scroll'.  This way it only loads once you get closer to needing the data.  ajaxProgressiveLoad set to 'load' will continuously load data, until all the data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the OP had set `progressiveLoad` to 'scroll', but Tabulator was continually requesting additional pages before the user scrolled the page. I had the same issue, but setting the height of the table solved the problem for me. For example, from the docs:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"300px",
    pagination:true, //enable.
});
```